# How to create this algebraic equation encoding basic choice?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Given 2 non negative, ordered real variables $x, y$ such that we know:

1. $x\geqslant y$
2. $x - y = d$
3. $x+y=1$

Given another variable $k$ such that either:

1. $k=0$ or
2. $k=d^2-d$

The objective is to construct a single algebraic equation such that:

1. The equation outputs $d$ when value of $k$ is non zero i.e. $k=d^2-d$.
2. It outputs 0 when $k$ is 0.

Essentially we are trying to encode a logical constraint in a simple mathematical equation. The simple approach is to take $d^2-d$ or 0 as the constant and solve the quadratic equation $x^2-x=k$ but it will give 2 results in each case:

1. $d$ and $1-d$
2. 0 and 1

How do we enforce the logic/selection using basic mathematical operations [+, - , *, /, abs()]. We are not allowed to use any logical operations or operations that internally use logic or require if/else kind of tests at any level as that defeats the original purpose and makes the problem trivial.

Been struggling with it for days can someone please help?

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ the inputs of the expression you seek?

Comment: we are given these 2 variables [but of course we do not know their values]

Comment: The operations you want to restrict yourself to are all _continuous_ (in their various domains), and therefore it is impossible to use them to build the _discontinuous_ function you have defined (namely, when $k=d^2-d$ you want $0$ for $y=0$ but $1-2y$ when $y>0$. If you're willing to divulge more about the "original purposes" that would "defeated" by other mechanisms is, it might be possible to point you in a useful direction, though.

Comment: thank you. I understand the problem wrt. the continuous and discontinuous one but that is where abs() function can help. We can use it to add the discontinuity to the eqn. with the sign change below and above 0 (i hope i am able to clarify this). I am working on a problem/algo in which this equation would fit as a black box [i duly and sincerely apologize if i can't divulge further so please don't take it in the wrong way]

Comment: No, the absolute-value function cannot help -- _it is continuous too_.

Comment: i think we can restrict part of the real number line with it at the point of our choosing. say for example ((x-.5)+abs(x-.5))+1 would return 2x when x is greater than .5 and 1 when x is less than .5

Comment: That is still a continuous function. Nothing new there; it won't help you create anything _discontinous_. This is not because you lack ingenuity -- it is a _general fact_, proved in elementary real analysis courses, that _everything_ you can possibly construct by composing continuous functions will itself be continuous.

Comment: I thought about it can this general version of the problem help: $k=d^2-d$ then output $d$ and $k=-(d^2-d)$ then output $-d$? doesn't it make the problem continuous?

Comment: No, there's still a discontinuity at $d=1$.

Comment: @Troposphere Hi. Please see the original problem here. I posted it as another Q. Now I am wondering if that can be rigorously provable to be impossible or can we solve it? I think we can. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4201355/how-do-we-create-the-following-algebraic-function-using-basic-arithmetic-operati